# Static foreach with method

Tags: c#

i want to make asynchronous loop accross my list and do the method Execute in paraller. I am wonder how i can achieve that.

This is my list:

```
public class MakeRequest
        {   
            public string file_READYTOTEST { get; set; }
            public string file_DONEFILE { get; set; }
            public string Inventory_name { get; set; }
            public string  TimeOutFP { get; set; }
            public Server server { get; set; }

        }
```

on final i got a lot elements addedto list like this by other foreach

```
IList<MakeRequest> makeRequestList;
    makeRequestList.Add(new MakeRequest { file_DONEFILE = DONEFILE, file_READYTOTEST = READYTOTEST, Inventory_name = file, server = SAMaddress, TimeOutFP = IO.TimeOutFP } );
```

and having that list of object i need to do some calculations

Explanation:

```
file_DONEFILE = final file name to be saved (string)
file_READYTOTEST = file which will be opened to do some operation then result save to file_DONEFILE (string)
Inventory_name = my inventory item (string)
server = server ip (string)
Timeout = path of file (string)
```

When i am doing in synchronous i am executing like this :

```
 foreach (MakeRequest item in makerequest)
                {
                    Execute(item.file_READYTOTEST, item.file_DONEFILE, item.Inventory_name, IO.TimeOutFP, item.server);
                }
```

and this is my methods:

```
//Create a soap webrequest to [Url]
        public static HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest(string ServerIP)
        {
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ServerIP);
            webRequest.Headers.Add(@"SOAP:Action");
            webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
            webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            return webRequest;
        }

        public static void Execute(string xmlFileRequest, string xmlFileResult, string InventoryElement, string TimeOutFile, Server server)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = CreateWebRequest(server.ServerIP);
            var soapEnvelopeXml = new XmlDocument();
            soapEnvelopeXml.Load(xmlFileRequest);
            using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream);
            }
            try
            {
                using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())

                {
                    using (var rd = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        string soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();

                        var xdoc = new XmlDocument();
                        xdoc.LoadXml(soapResult);
                        xdoc.Save(xmlFileResult);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(TimeOutFile))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(InventoryElement);
                }
            }
        }
```

Could you please help me out how i can make it asynchronous.

---

UPDATE NR 2 on topic for futrther discussion:

---

```
    foreach (MakeRequest item in makeRequestList)
                {
    //1) no definition for run ...
                    Task.Run(() => Execute(item.file_READYTOTEST, item.file_DONEFILE, item.Inventory_name, IO.TimeOutFP, item.server));
                }

    //2. I want to wait on all threads to end before Console.Writeline("All...
                Task.WaitAll(task);

    Console.Writeline("All Tasks have been done")
    Console.Readline()

//other piece of code:
    //3. Catch case: (where to define locker?)

        }
                    catch (WebException e)
                    {
        lock(locker)
        {
                        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(TimeOutFile))
                        {
                            sw.WriteLine(InventoryElement);
                        }
                    }
        }
```

---

UPDATE NR 3 on topic for futrther discussion:

---

```
  List<Task> mytasks = new List<Task>();
        foreach (MakeRequest item in makeRequestList)
        {

            Task myFirstTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Execute(item.file_READYTOTEST, item.file_DONEFILE, item.Inventory_name, IO.TimeOutFP, item.server) );
            mytasks.Add(myFirstTask);
        }

        Task.WaitAll(mytasks.ToArray());

Console.writeline("Something");
Console.readline();
```

Comment: Where is `makerequest` used in your code?

Comment: I guess somewhere you use a for/foreach loop to iterate over a lit and call Execute for each item. One solution would be to simply use a Parallel.For/ForEach construct instead.

Comment: i cannot make Execute inside foreach as asynchoronous becase threads could change: item.file_READYTOTEST, item.file_DONEFILE during some other thread using diffrent value and could overwrite. Otherhand Making whole foreach doesnt make sense to make full foreach on lock becase then i get same result as without it. What can you advice me in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Task` to make it async:

```
foreach (MakeRequest item in makerequest)
{
    Task.Run( () => Execute(item.file_READYTOTEST, item.file_DONEFILE, item.Inventory_name, IO.TimeOutFP, item.server) );
}
```

Comment: ye but what is the guaranty that each task thread will not overwrite item.file_READYTOTEST & item.file_DONEFILE during execution by another task and finally result could be completly wrong. I belive i need to do so using somehow lock somwhere and Task of course.

Comment: `item` is a single instance right, only referenced within the loop? So there is no possibility it is overwritten in your current code.

Comment: yes i know there will be no problem with item - but each loop executing Execute() method and that method will be executed also by threads in same time and here is my objection - Dont you think some incomming values of one thread could ovverwrite other thread current incomming values to that method? or i am in wrong?

Comment: No, that is impossible. Calling the same method simultaneously will not cause parameters to be overwritten.

Comment: You mean because those incoming value item.file_READYTOTEST, item.file_DONEFILE foreach thread will be diffren according to new comming element from my list right?

Comment: Yes, it is. If you are passing the same variable again, there is a risk, but not now.

Comment: ok got it i think dont you think i need somewhere in my code additional lock() expecially inside Execute() method or CreateWebRequest() ? Maybe oon Streamwriter inside Execute method good to make lock() on it?

Comment: Maybe your exception handling, but nowhere else I can see.

Comment: you mean as i mentioned : to make lock() on whole using Streamwriter in catch statment becaue there can be risk right?

Comment: Yes, you can clash there.

Comment: and what about this line: HttpWebRequest request = CreateWebRequest(server.ServerIP) couldnt be there any risk? Take a look as CreateWebRequest is not new for all threads is the same or because string serveriP is same for all will be not a problem?

Comment: @Notification: Are you going to change the server ip in the meantime? If not, there is no risk.

Comment: Please check updated code in first post in bottom i made three points would like to clarify please.

Comment: 1. If using < .NET 4, use TaskFactory.StartNew. 2. Create a list and put every task in it. Then `Task.WaitAll(list.ToArray())`. 3. Define it in the class: `object locker = new object()`.

Comment: could you please check update nr.3 in first post is this correct ?

Comment: It's fine. That's the way to do it.

Comment: i got exception on item.Start(): Start may not be called on a task that was already started.

Comment: Because it was. Don't call `Start` again.

Comment: I have some error first time see it since when it was synchronous i didnt have that error on line: using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream()) error msg: The operation has timed out (Webexception has timed out) . I have timed out previously but on diffrent line: using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse()) then i knew that the particular response elemnt not responding and take him into timeputed file. Now after that implementation of tasks and lock code working diffrent. could you please help investigate why its like that?

Comment: Can you please post it as separate, complete question? It's hard to go from one to another question.

Comment: ok i will make another topic please if you could go folow it i will name it : "Implementation of tasks in current program/issue with WebResponse"

Comment: I made another topic please go in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25483524/implementation-of-tasks-in-current-program-issue-with-webresponse

Answer (score 0):

if your working framework is greater or equal to 3.5 you can use thread class to run into another loop.

```
Thread threadObj = null;
foreach (MakeRequest item in makerequest)
{
    threadObj = new Thread(new ThreadStart(()=>Execute(item.file_READYTOTEST, item.file_DONEFILE, item.Inventory_name, IO.TimeOutFP, item.server) ));
}
```